# define generic TObjectList<T> that type T is determine at run time

Tags: oop, delphi

suppose i have class like this:

```
    TUserClass = class of TObject;

    TMyClass = class(TObject)
    private
      FUserList: TObjectList<TUserClass>; {compile error here}
    public 
      constructor Create(AUserClass: TUserClass);
    end;

    TMyClass.Create(AUserClass: TUserClass);
    begin
      inherited;

      FUserList := TObjectList<AUserClass>.Create;
    end;
```

i want to TMyClass create FUserList whereas AUserClass determine at run time.
now i have compile error as i shown in the code that says "Type Parameter 'T' must be class type".
any idea what shall i do?

Comment: As David says, you cannot define your generic class at run time. And really it makes no sense to. You must know at design time what you are dealing with, because you cannot design a class at run time. So you must know the classes that you are dealing with at run time. Generally what you are trying to do would be dealt with by simply using polymorphism. You descend your classes from a common base class and use an object list of that base class. Then you don't even need generics. So what is special about your case that makes generics desirable?

Answer (score 2):

Generic instantiation occurs at compile time and so you cannot specify the type parameter at runtime.

As for what to do, it depends on the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: TMyClass that is suppose to work for two type of user who has different properties. i don't want create its classes outside of TMyClass.

Comment: I still don't know enough to give you advice. I think I answered the question of how to make a generic which is instantiated at runtime.

Comment: @AminAlinezhad That sounds like making TMyclass generic would suffice.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes I know, but I think the OP is probably overthinking it. I am just trying to guide him in the right direction.